# How to generate admin class from symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-3.3, symfony-flex

How to generate  admin class for one entity with symfony flex project and SonataAdmin?

There are not more bundles, so "The bundle name:" fail on generating admin class.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: have you tried this: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/creating_an_admin.html ?

Comment: Yes, it work creating the admin class by hand same with the entities. But problem is generating it by console commands because there aren't Bundles any more, my folder structure is src/app, no AppBundle i'm using symfony flex to make compatible with sf 4 folder structure